# Are index aliases and wildcard index endpoints in Elasticsearch exactly the same thing?

Tags: performance, rest, indexing, elasticsearch

The Elasticsearch documentation for [Index Aliases](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html) says:

> The index aliases API allow to alias an index with a name, with all
>   APIs automatically converting the alias name to the actual index name.
>   An alias can also be mapped to more than one index, and when
>   specifying it, the alias will automatically expand to the aliases
>   indices.

And the documentation for [Multiple Indices](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/multi-index.html) says:

> Most APIs that refer to an `index` parameter support execution across
>   multiple indices, using simple `test1,test2,test3` notation (or `_all` for
>   all indices). It also support wildcards, for example: `test*`, and the
>   ability to "add" (`+`) and "remove" (`-`), for example: `+test*,-test3`.

**Scenario #1**

1. You have 12 monthly indices from the year 2014 each named with a date pattern, e.g. `someprefix_2014-07`
2. You map all of these indices to an alias named `2014`.
3. Both of these requests would return the same result:

   - `$ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/someprefix_2014-*/_stats`
   - `$ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/2014/_stats`

**Scenario #2**

1. You have a total of 24 monthly indices in your cluster and you decide you want to target all of them.
2. All of these requests would return the same result:

   - `$ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_stats`
   - `$ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_all/_stats`
   - `$ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/*/_stats`
   - `$ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/someprefix_*/_stats`

**My Question**

*Are all of these methods doing the same thing "under the hood", or is there one that may expect better performance than the others?*

I ask because I've read about [Wildcard Queries](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) being a common performance bottleneck, but I've never seen any similar warning for using aliases or wildcards in index endpoints - or distinguishing default aliases (like `_all`) from custom ones.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They aren't *exactly* the same, from a code execution perspective.  But they are functionally identical and will have identical performance profiles.

Aliases are really just "tags" that are attached to existing indices.  So when you search against the `2014` alias, Elasticsearch just scans through the list of indices in the cluster state and finds all indices that are tagged with that alias.

When you search against a wildcard index pattern, it scans through the list of indices to see which names match the regex.

So performance will basically be the same, because the actual search is entirely unaffected:  the shards associated with those searches will be queried no matter what, and all the index-to-shard lookups will happen on the coordinating node very quickly, no matter the method used.

So don't worry, you can choose whichever makes more sense for you :)

PS. Wildcard queries are discouraged because they *do* have performance implications.  They have to generate and check a large number of potential tokens, which can have non-negligible impact on latency.  But they are very different from index wildcards, or many other wildcards around ES.  Most things that support pattern matching / wildcards in ES are simply Java regex, whereas the `wildcard` query is fancy automaton magic inside of Lucene against inverted indices...much different :)

Comment: Thanks very much for that insight! Plus it's exactly what I wanted to hear :-)

Comment: Those are the best kinds of answers! :)